# How to handle continual method addition to an existing class

Tags: c#, class-design

I find myself often adding more and more methods to a specific class, is this class heading in an unmaintainable direction? Or is this class fine even if it has 50 or more methods?

let's call the class `PowerSource182`, it handles the details of creating commands that are sent to a "PowerSource182" power supply (an external device), allowing for the rest of the code to simply call `myPowerSource.Operate()`. This piece of equipment has hundreds of commands, and I only implement a subset of these commands, but have needed to expand the subset repeatability as commands become needed.

Each addition is still cohesive to the class's intended scope of responsibility, further more they are so cohesive I don't see it reasonable to separate them into smaller groups.

Here is a example of what `PowerSource182` looks like, here I use a `IInstrument` which is a class that simple handles write, read, and query commands to a serial port, gpib, or some other communication protocol.

```
public class PowerSource182
{
    IInstrument _instrument;

    public PowerSource(IInstrument instrument)
    {
        _instrument = instrument;
        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _instrument.Command("*RST");
    }

    public void StandBy()
    {
        _instrument.Command("STBY");
    }

    public void Operate()
    {
        _instrument.Command("OPER");
    }

    public string GetFaults()
    {
        return _instrument.Query("FAULTS?");
    }

    public enum InternalConstant
    {
        L1S = 1,
        L2S = 2,
        L3S = 3,
        L4S = 4,
        L5S = 5,
        L6S = 6,
    }

    public void SetInternalConstant(InternalConstant internalConstant, double value)
    {
        _instrument.Command($"seticon {internalConstant.ToString()}, {value}");
    }

    public enum Function
    {
        VOLTS = 0,
        AMPS = 1,
    }

    public void SetOutput(Function func, double value, double frequency = 0)
    {
        string funcString = funcString.First().ToString();

        _instrument.Command($"OUT {value} {funcString}, {frequency} HZ");
    }

    public enum Events
    {
        OPC = 1,
        TEX = 2,
        LOP = 4,
        DFT = 8,
        PMW = 16,
    }
    public bool GetEventStatusRegister(Events e)
    {
        int mask = (int)e;
        int eventStatusRegister = int.Parse(_instrument.Query("*ESR?"));
        bool result = (eventStatusRegister & mask) == mask;

        return result;
    }
}
```

This example is not the actual source, but I hope it illustrates the problem.

Comment: If the class is cohesive, then there is no reason to split it up. People worry about "God classes", but the problem with God classes is when the functionality is not cohesive, not the size itself.

Comment: Besides the size of there source code file, are you encountering any problems with this design?

Comment: @GregBurghardt As more functions are added I feel like the class is just getting too large for others to easily know what all is implemented. Maybe that really is just the nature of the class, as I have to refer to the manual for the product when I create a new method for the class.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add comments to methods or enums if the names are unclear. You could even refer back to the manual in those comments. It could be as simple as `///<summary>... (see page X of Y manual)`.

Comment: Do the order these methods get called matter? For instance, can I call `GetFaults()` at any point? Can I call `Reset()` before calling `Operate()`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Each command can be called in any order, the actual equipment will even let you put them in one message like `"*RST; OUT 10V, 10Hz; OPER;"` they can all be called at any point and in any order, though that may change the final state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by adding new methods you mean to add new responsibilities to the class then you might consider using the [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern#:%7E:text=In%20object-oriented%20design%2C%20the%20chain-of-responsibility%20pattern%20is%20a,to%20the%20next%20processing%20object%20in%20the%20chain).

But if adding new methods is simply a matter of updates then you might use partial classes to divide your class into smaller chunks of code for improved readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is opinion-based, and you could break up the class with other classes, but you shouldn't really get hung-up on number of lines of code. What you should focus on is using the "Don't repeat yourself" (DRY) principle, and keeping this to a single responsibility. If that still results in a lot of code per class, then it's just the nature of the beast.